# JS Canvas fillStyle works incorrectly

Tags: javascript, canvas

fillStyle doesn't work properly with:

```
function draw_grd (x,y,r,c1,c2) {
    var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, r);
    gradient.addColorStop(0,c1);
    gradient.addColorStop(1,c2);
    ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fill();
}

draw_grd(50,50,50,"white","blue");
draw_grd(150,50,50,"green","red");
draw_grd(250,50,50,"black","pink");
```

And the result is:

[image]

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/dsart/vogqzjnc/5/

What is it that I am missing? How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ctx.beginPath();` before `ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);` and it should work fine.
The problem here is that with your multiple function calls, you essentially chain the drawing paths together and your previous call has an impact on the next call.

Here is the modified version: http://jsfiddle.net/ghbLzy72/69/

Please note that I changed `var` to `const`. It's a good practice to use the new keywords (`let` and `const`) to initialize variables. You can leave this change out from your code if you prefer using `var`, but be aware of it's consequences and the impact it might have on your code (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/).